# Adobe Business Catalyst End of Life, website migration recommendations

Tags: migrate, business-catalyst

So Adobe announced they are ending Business Catalyst in March 2020. I need to migrate a current website and blog. What would be some good options? I am telling my client that we should stick with a regular HTML site. However, I am unsure how to migrate the blog? Am I going to have to use wordpress, or is there another way? I really want to stay away from Wordpress in fear of that it will not last forever either. Also, options for the forms? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your website link so everyone can get a better idea of what you need to migrate.

You should look into WooCommerce and Shopify - both great options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Its a html responsive small business website, about 30 pages not an ecommerce one just informational. Has a blog and a few forms to generate leads.

Answer (score 0):

The BC community has been evaluating several CMS options since End-Of-Life was announced. Join the Adobe Business Catalyst Partners Facebook group to [learn more](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1460931824128318/), and watch the relevant [BC Sandpile](https://www.bcsandpile.com/meetings) videos which showcase some of the alternatives.

I just migrated a BC site that made extensive use of web apps to WordPress and I found that WordPress + custom post types + [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) + [Gravity Forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/) offers the BC experience we love plus a whole lot more. Managed hosting via [WP Engine](https://wpengine.com/) or [Flywheel](https://getflywheel.com/) offers the performance and security of BC while avoiding some of the security issues that WordPress can be associated with.